# How to make condition if "result code":"0" in android

Tags: java, android, jsonresult

I am getting server response like "resultcode":"10" and I want to make condition if resultcode is 0 then do something .How can I do that

```
if (response.getString("resultDesc").equalsIgnoreCase("Transaction Successful")) {}
```

Here I want to replace Transaction successful with "0"

Comment: why not use simple if?need code for that?

Comment: String equality checks?

Comment: Not all bdy 0 and 1 is set yes or no condition...ex: u set 1 is male and 0 is female

Comment: You can try with simple if and also simply use equals() instead of  equalsIgnoreCase()

Comment: Can you please share the entire JSON string/array.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
int val = response.getInt("resultCode");
if(val.equals(0)){
//do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first get result code from jsonobject and parse it into int and then use it in if condition.

```
 int resultcode = Integer.parseInt(jsonObject.getString("resultcode"));
                 if (resultcode == 0) {
                 //Do Your code

                 }
```